# Connecting through XMLA using JDBC

Tags: jdbc, ssas, xmla

I'm trying to connect to SpagoBI using a XMLA data source.

This is my JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:xmla:Server=http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll;
```

And I'm using this driver:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I'm trying to connect to a SSAS cube. This is how the configuration looks like now:

[image: Data source]

But Tomcat keeps telling "no suitable driver found".

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Update:

I wasn't using the correct driver. the SQLServerDriver is only for SQL Server, not for SSAS. Does anyone know what driver could I use?

Comment: I would think that the driver that you are using is one for the relational database of SQL Server (tables) - and you have to talk SQL to it, while the URL you are using is for the Analysis Services component of SQL Server (cubes) - and you have to talk XMLA to it. This just does not fit. What type of source do you want to access?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to my SSAS cube through XMLA. I have also tried with this driver:

org.jdbc4olap.jdbc.OlapDriver

But it doesn't work, either.

Comment: What type of connection does SpagoBI require? Does it talk XMLA? MDX? SQL?

Comment: SpagoBI talks XMLA. My project is also exposing XMLA, but I don't know which driver I could use :(

Comment: If it talks XMLA, then I am not sure you need a driver at all. Technically, what the msmdpump.dll in IIS expects, is a http request sending an XMLA request within a SOAP request, and it delivers a SOAP response containing the result as defined in the XMLA specification.

Comment: Does the vendor of SpagoBI not have a support who can help you setting this up?

Comment: They do have support, but it's very bad, unless you spend 2.000 dollars. I discarded using SpagoBI. Thanks anyway !!

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server driver has a purpose for connecting JPA-based applications to relational databases based on MSSQL Server. MS Analysis Services is not a relational database; it is a OLAP solution for storing data cubes.

You need to find another way to connect to MS Analysis Services. One solution is to send XMLA or MDX queries to the URL you posted (actually, to the DLL) using a socket connection or an HTTP client.